# date calculations in bash

Tags: bash, date, awk

I have a simple question.

```
date '+%Y%m%d' --date='20130417 2 day ago'
20130415
```

works fine.

I have an env var

```
today="20130417"
```

but the following command does not work.

```
date '+%Y%m%d' --date='$today 2 day ago'
```

any workarounds?

Comment: use a parameter's name within braces. `"" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need double quotes instead of single:

```
$ date '+%Y%m%d' --date="$today 2 day ago"
20130415
```

Otherwise, the values within `--date=' '` don't get evaluated.

This is a general behaviour, see an example:

```
$ echo 'the date is: $today'
the date is: $today

$ echo "the date is: $today"
the date is: 20130417
```

Comment: @user3652962 `date '+%Y%m%d' --date="$today +2 day"` should make it. It works to me at least.

Comment: Yes...Thanks fedorqui. This works too. 
And personally I prefer this way because sometimes I need to go in future and past, and its easy to remember.